# Gnome/Nvidia driver installation fails after upgrading to Wheezy

Tags: debian, nvidia

I upgraded one of my Debian 6 machines to Debian 7 but the graphical login never appears. All I get is a blinking cursor. When I switch to tty and try to install the proprietary Nvidia driver, something strange happens: the Nvidia installer warns me that I should use gcc 4.6 since my 2.6 kernel is built with this version of gcc. I am actually using Linux 3.2 and I purged all 2.6.* kernels from the system after the upgrade. When I continue, I get this error `ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.` The log file contains exactly the same message.

I use Debian 7.6, kernel linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 (3.2.60-1+deb7u3), driver NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-280.13.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that went away when I changed the link that gcc went to. (from gcc-4.7 to gcc-4.6)

To see where 'gcc' points:

```
ls -al `which gcc`
```

Then change the link with something like:

```
sudo ln -s -f gcc-4.6 /usr/bin/gcc
```

p.s.
For me NVidia drivers used to be working, but now when I try them, it seams that as soon as I start doing stuff in KDE (like left clicking on things) it crashes, so I'm back to using nouveau drivers.

To go back to nouveau use the NVidia installer's `--uninstall` option, then delete(or move for backup) the '/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf', and the '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' files, and then install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau. 
(or at least I think doing this is what got nouveau back :) )